# Horizontal RecyclerView doesn't scroll in Android 7?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add a horizontal view in an activity, this view have a button to add image and then a list of added images, I used this code.

.XML file

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <!-- some views-->

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_add_image"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_border_gray"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/add_grey" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>        

       <!-- some views-->
</LinearLayout>
```

Java file

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_book);

    ...
    ...
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, 
    LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mAdapter = new ImagesAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

This code is working very well in android M and below but the [recyclerview](/questions/tagged/recyclerview) doesn't scroll in Android N, I looked to more answers but I didn't find a way to help me to solve this.
any help, please.

Comment: I dont know why It was working for previous versions. But what you can do is add a new view type in your recycler view and inflate that in your first position.

Comment: Thank you @muditsen1234 I will do this if didn't find another simple solution.

Comment: well this method works for all the versions